# Angular CLI and Angular version difference

Tags: angular

What is difference in installing angular and angular cli does they mean the same?

Does installing angular cli mean installing angular are they bundled.

How to identify angular version based on angular cli version

Answer (score 2):

### Angular-CLI is:

- A build tool: a command line tool used to generate and initialize an
  angular project.
- A development tool: used to add components, services and custom
  directives to the angular project.
- A service: to run your project to see and interact with the
  application while developing.

### Angular:

As we hear about different versions, angular 2, 4, 6..., is a platform, a framework and an MVC architecture that is used to build client side single page applications that can run in a web browser.The architecture consists of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Most common language used in developing angular application is Typescript which gives an OOP like structure to angular and is a wrapper on JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**Angular-CLI** a command line interface and it is a TOOL to create your angular application. It provides commands to generate code such as components, services and directives to make angular application development easier to the developer. It also allows you to build your application and serve your application as you are developing.

**angular cli** can report its version when you run

```
ng --version
```

Comment: I tried and below is what i got . Angular CLI: 1.6.2
Node: 8.9.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: ...    The angular version does not shows

Comment: You could also check your package.json file it contains all the details.